# Garamond kills bold Fonts

Tags: fonts, garamond

*[Cross posted from latex-community.org]*

When I use Garamond fonts, everything becomes immediately lighter, in particular the \begin{description} … \end{description} parts.

With Garamond:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{garamond}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction and Ideas}
\begin{description}
\item[Item 1]
\item[Item 2]
\end{description}

\section{More Ideas}

\end{document}
```

Without Garamond:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

%\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage{garamond}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction and Ideas}
\begin{description}
\item[Item 1]
\item[Item 2]
\end{description}

\section{More Ideas}

\end{document}
```

How can I get around this? Thanks

Comment: (Warning: Pedantic Comment!) Strictly speaking, since Garamond is an early, classical font, it shouldn't be used with bold characters; just roman, italic, and (maybe) small caps. "Bold is modern stuff".

Comment: How do you get it to compile at all? I just get compilation errors.

Answer (score 7):

Some suggestions:

1. Use **T1** font encoding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
2. **URW Garamond** usually is not included in any TeX distribution. So, it usually requires manual download and installation. It's here [**urw-garamond**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond) for example.
3. There is an alternative way to use **URW Garamond**, via the package `mathdesign`. It also provides math font, which math font isn't the best, but it's Garamond based. It's here [**mathdesign**](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathdesign/) and is invoked this way `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`

Answer (score 3):

This answer is because there are problems with the other answers.

I am using TeXLive, and I have installed the non-free fonts with `getnonfreefonts`. In my document, I want to use Garamond for the serif and another (in my opinion nicely matching) typeface for the sans-serif. Using KOMA-Script (don't know if this is relevant).

If I use:

```
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
```

then the sans-serif text indeed loses at least bold and small caps.

The solution for me was to use [EB Garamond](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/), with:

```
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Note that some of the styles are not shown on the [page linked above](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ebgaramond/), for example bold, but `\textbf{text}` works as expected for me.

More importantly, all text typeset in Sans-Serif still keeps all styles as intended!

Comment: EB Garamond does not include bold.

Comment: did not work for me. I wonder why the example sheet on the package's page shows bold garamond fonts. https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond/doc/ebgaramond-samples.pdf

Answer (score 2):

garamond does not kill bold fonts. You need to separately install garamond bold fonts to generate bold face characters. Similarly for italics and other fonts. For example if you are using "Garamond Pro", \textbf will work only if you have "Garamond Pro Bold" font installed.

Comment: It does mess up with styles somehow. If you have a sans-serif in your document, then the styles on it (bold, small caps) will disappear when you load garamond.

Answer (score 2):

The free EB Garamond family [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/).  Since it is OpenType, you can use it in all your applications, not merely TeX.  Only a subset of it ships with TeX Live (as of July 2018).

I personally recommend that you use the modern `fontspec` toolchain unless you are forced to stick with the legacy encodings for the sake of backward compatibility.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}[
  BoldFont = EBGaramond-Bold,
  ItalicFont = EBGaramond-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = EBGaramond-BoldItalic]
```

There is even [a Garamond Math font](https://github.com/YuanshengZhao/Garamond-Math) in OpenType, usable with `unicode-math`, although it is a work in progress.

A sample of the font family:

[image: EB Garamond with Garamond Math]

Answer (score 0):

I used cormorantgaramond instead of EBgaramond and it seems to work just fine, since it produces bold as well as italic fonts

Comment: That leaves much to wonder in terms of how and why. Can you elaborate?