# How can I bold a word using EB Garamond font

Tags: fonts, bold

I am trying to figure out how to bold "LaTeX University".  How do I go about doing this?  What I have now (i.e., "\textbf{LaTeX University}" is not working for some reason with my used font *EB Garamond*.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{textgreek}

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{varwidth}
\geometry{margin=1.75in}

\title{{\Large{Curriculum Vitae}}}


\date{}

\author{}
\singlespacing
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{\normalsize{Contact}}



\section*{\normalsize{Education}}

\begin{itemize}


\item \textbf{LaTeX University} \\
\vspace{-5mm}

\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21323/garamond-kills-bold-fonts

Comment: Since boldface found its way in typography several decades after the work of Garamont (Garamond) and Granjon, using boldface with such fonts is like actors wearing wristwatches in Ben Hur.

Answer (score 3):

The `EB Garamond` font family doesn't provide **bold** or ***bold italic*** font faces. You need to switch to a Garalde (short for "Garamond-Aldus [Manutius]) font that does provide these additional font faces.

Not knowing what operating system and TeX distribution you employ, it's not easy to give a definitive suggestion, except that you should switch to LuaLaTeX so that you can make use of system fonts. Hopefully, your OS features (at least) one of Adobe Garamond Pro, Palatino, and Junicode. If not, I'm sure you'll be able to locate some other suitable Garalde font on your system.

Some additional comments about your code: (a) If you want to bold the title ("Curriculum Vitae"), don't use the `\title`-`\maketitle` device, as it switches to the normal (non-bold) font weight for the argument of `title`. (b) Consider using the `sectsty` package and making `\normalsize` the default font size for all sectioning headers.

[image]

---

Aside: **Bold** and ***bold italic*** font faces did not exist during the lifetimes of Aldus Manutius and Claude Garamond. If you want to show some real (typographic!) sophistication while using a Garalde, consider writing your document without any bold-facing tricks.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\geometry{margin=1.75in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing

\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\normalsize}

\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %% Choose a suitable Garalde:
  %\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}
  %\setmainfont{Junicode} 
  \setmainfont{Palatino}
\else
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{ebgaramond}
  \usepackage{textgreek}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\Large\bfseries Curriculum Vitae
\end{center}

\section*{Contact}

\section*{Education}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{LaTeX University}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Strange: on the sample sheet for package ebgaramond, there --are-- bold fonts https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond/doc/ebgaramond-samples.pdf

Comment: @Arnaud - I wrote this answer nearly two years ago, and I was referring to the *original version* of the EB Garamond font, which was created by Georg Duffner (now Georg Mayr-Duffner) alone and was last updated in 2014. The version you've come across, which is the version now being distributed with TeXLive, is the one which was *recently* taken over Octavio Pardo. The original EB-Garamond font still lacks **bold** and ***bold-italic*** font faces; cf. http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/ and (for downloading the font files) https://bitbucket.org/georgd/eb-garamond/downloads/.

Comment: thanks for the complementary information. Despite the fact that it now has bold fonts, I did not manage to use them with (pdf)LaTeX. As far as I understood,  they only work with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Arnaud - Have you tried loading the `ebgaramond` *package*?

Comment: I'm on TeXLive 2017, that's probably the problem

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{textgreek}

% \usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\usepackage{varwidth}
\geometry{margin=1.75in}

\title{{\Large{Curriculum Vitae}}}


\date{}

\author{}
\singlespacing
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section*{\normalsize{Contact}}



\section*{\normalsize{Education}}

\begin{itemize}


\item \textbf{LaTeX University} \\
\vspace{-5mm}

\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But I'd like to keep the Garamond font.  Any way to keep this font and bold?

Comment: This only "works" because you've done the equivalent of assuming away the problem, by switching to a font family that does feature a bold font face...